# How to insert a semicolon before last character in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to add a semicolon before the last character in a column (A:A).

I want to change the value in specific cells from e.g. GLA-12342 to GLA-1234;2

This should only be done on cells that contains the following text: 
GLA, GLX, GLV, GLY, GLC

Are there some nice VBA-guru out there who could help me with this

What I got sofar is this...

```
Sub Semikolon()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("A:A")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "GLA") > 0 Then

         '   Can not figure out how to solve this...


    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the output in another column a simple formula will do this.

Comment: I would like to have it in the same column since i´m exporting the data.

Comment: Then see @Pᴇʜ comment.

Comment: Updated my post...

Comment: `cel.Value = left(cel.value,len(cel.value)-1) & ";" & Right(cel.value,1)`

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. Just use `Left$` and `Right$` functions to split the string on the correct place.

Also I recommend to limit the `SrchRng` to the used cells only to speed it up.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Semikolon()
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    Dim Cel As Range
    For Each Cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, Cel.Value, "GLA") > 0 Or _
           InStr(1, Cel.Value, "GLX") > 0 Then 'add more or statements here

            Cel.Value = Left$(Cel.Value, Len(Cel.Value) - 1) & ";" & Right$(Cel.Value, 1)              
        End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Comment: @Daniel, please mark the answer as solved by clicking the grey tick mark below the voting buttons. It shows other people that the question is solved and give both of you some credit points :). And welcome to Stackoverflow! =)